# javascript http get request for web service

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm implementing a new ftp product at work that has the ability to run adhoc ftp jobs via a web service call. The web service only has two parameters that can be passed to it, rule name and rule params. The web service returns 0 or 1 dependent upon success or failure in this format:

http://ftpwebservicesite.com>1

The web service requires authentication which I can't provide when calling from our mainframe.

I have the ability to call the web service via an http get request. The problem that I'm running into is that when using this method, the tool I'm using doesn't see the failure returned by the web service as a failure rather it see the http 200 code and marks it as a success.

Is there any way to set up a middle man web page that calls the web service via http get, parses the response and then returns an http code of 200 for 1 and a 400 http code for 0?

Comment: show us the codes, but basically, call/apply your onerror in your onload if you get a 0.

Comment: @dandavis would you have an example, i am new at this.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible by request to access any web server out of your current context.
You can make an middle page, with another language server sided. (you can do it easly with php and curl) and request the data from middle page

PHP mode:

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init('http://www.yahoo.com/');

    curl_exec($ch);

    if(!curl_errno($ch))
    {
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

        echo ( $info['total_time'] == 200 ? 1 : 0 );
    }

    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Anything like this, i didn`t tested, but should work!

Comment: unfortunately i do not have access to php.